# Help to reduce size of .obj file?

Tags: modeling

I am new to Blender and 3D modeling.  We purchased some 3D models of some beverage packaging containers we use but they seem to have too many polygons.  I downloaded Blender and followed the advice of a few tutorials and videos to reduce them but am really struggling.  I simply need to make one file less than 200,000 polygons for a online application we are trying to use.  Would anyone be willing to help with this?

It is a simple ask, but trying to learn Blender for this one small project feels unecessary.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe try using a Decimate Modifier? If your object is round(ish), try "collapse", if your object is flat(ish), try "planar".

Comment: Hello, is your object photoscanned ? You can use the decimate modifier, or use the remesh modifier and play with the settings

Comment: Hello and welcome. This site goal is to build a high quality database of questions and answers. If your goal is not learning and you just want to have someone do it for you, then it is best to ask elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

Can you post the model somewhere?

If you can import the model successfully, Select it, go to the **Modifiers Tab** and add the Decimate modifier.  Under the **Decimate** modifier, there are three "modes" for it to work: **Collapse, Un-Subdivide**, and **Planar**.  If you are going to be using the model in a game engine, you might want to skip the Planar setting because it will give you n-gons.  You might also want to check the "**Triangulate**" box - then play with the "**Ratio**" slider until you get the polycount and visual quality you want.  \

Poly reduction is more forgiving on organic shapes (you can get away with more "generic" reduction).  If the shapes are very clean/defined, generic reduction might not work very well and you would have to consider hand-reduction or retopologizing.

If/When you are happy with your result, you can go to the drop-down arrow in the Decimate modifier panel and select "Apply" and export your model (or, you can export your model straight-up - but you want to make sure the "Apply Modifiers" option is active under the export options).